# How do I save user input content in the view and do a post call to the controller when navigate away from page, silently

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, onbeforeunload

So the title says what I want to accomplish.  Here's what I'm working with:

Microsoft MVC4
Razor views

```
Model
class Model1
{
    public string var1 {get; set;}
    public bool ExitPage {get; set;}
}
```

the view is cshtml, and looks something like this:

```
@using Models
@model Model1

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    bool notFromSubmit = false;

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ExitPage)
    @Html.Hidden("ExitPage", Model.ExitPage)

    Model.ExitPage = false;

    <article class="widget widgetFullPage" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h2 id="contactDetails">GENERAL INFORMATION</h2>
        <table>
            <tr id="Row1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td style="width: 200px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 20px"><label>Var1</label></td>
                <td id="var1Id" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px; width: 300px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.var1, null, new { style = "width:100px;" })
                </td>
                <td style="width: 250px; padding-top: 20px;"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="Row2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="float: right; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px">
                    <input value=" " class="nextbutton loading" type="submit" id="NextButton" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </article>

}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#NextButton").on('click', function () {
        if (window.notFromSubmit) {
            document.getElementById('ExitPage').value = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('ExitPage').value = false;
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
           if (window.event) {
               window.notFromSubmit = true;
               $("#CaseManagementNextButton").click();
           }
           return null;
        };
    });

</script>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is when the next button is hit, it does the post back with the save, and the controller will redirect the user to the next page.  Where as when the user navigates away/close the page, it will set the ExitPage variable on the model so the controller will just do the save and exit.

This mostly works, only that I have to do this silently (no popup dialog). however, using the "onbeforeunload" event.  Even when returning null, it's still poping up a confirmation box and want to make the user choose to stay or to leave.  Is there a way to not have the dialog box pop up and just do the leave action and still trigger the click event on the next button? When I comment out the return, it does not popup the dialog box, but it also does not execute the nextbutton click event.

Any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: It seems like this is an async operation and should be handled with ajax. Clicking the button is causing a postback which will reload the page with the new variables. Instead, catch the button click with javascript, do your logic and decide whether the form should be submitted or something else should happen.

Comment: What's your goal here? Do you truly want to save the partial form or do you just want to allow the user to continue from where they left off later? If you don't literally need the info on your end until the user is ready to submit it, then local storage is better option.

Comment: The goal is to save the user input when they navigate away from the page by any means short of a power off, with out any popup to prompt the save.

Comment: I don't believe there is a reliable, consistent, "silent" way to do this. Consider silently saving in the background via ajax at set intervals instead.

Comment: Saving at periodic intervals would not work, since the accepted interval would be very short (every 5 seconds at most), and that would cause massive performance issues if we need to post back everything on the page every 5 seconds, and even then it is still not acceptable to the customer as data entered in between the 5 second save intervals would be lost if they navigate away.... Is there really no way to trigger this kind of save silently?

Answer (score 0):

add onblur="myFunction(), then do asynch call to controller.